# Do the same thing for 4 conditions else do something else

Tags: lua

I have a system that I need translate to Lua. The code is to read an XML file.

`cat = elementAttributeTable["Category"] -- This will be 3 char code.`

Now, if `cat` is e.g. "MUS" or "MUA" or "XMS", I need to process other `elementAttributeTable[]` information. Else do some default stuff.

I have seen some info using a Table, but can't find an `if in_table()` thing.
Other languages have the `Select...Case`, that I don't see in Lua.

How could I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One straightforward way to express this is using `or`:

```lua
if cat == "MUS" or cat == "MUA" or cat == "XMS" then
    -- process information
else
    -- default behavior
end
```

given the few values you are testing for, this is completely fine.

You might want to write yourself a helper:

```lua
local function equals_any(value, ...)
    local n = select("#", ...)
    for i = 1, n do
        if value == select(i, ...) then
            return true
        end
    end
    return false
end
```

Usage: `if equals_any(cat, "MUS", "MUA", "XMS") then ... end`.

Alternatively, if you want a more "data-driven" approach or have many more categories to check for (such that it negatively affects performance), you could use a table:

```lua
local categories = {MUS = true, MUA = true, XMS = true}
if categories[cat] then
    -- process information
else
    -- default behavior
end
```

Comment: I like the looks of "data-driven" version, but will also test the equals_any() version. Thank you.